# C CSV Parsing and storing

Tags: c, csv

I am trying to write my first CSV parsing program. I am trying to read data from a CSV file and store it. Once stored I have to perform some calculations on certain data points. I am really struggling with the multiple commas in this CSV file it seems to be making the task more challenging (,,,,,).

The CSV file I am parsing uses the following format:

```
2020-01-26,,,1,,,,,,,9,,,,,,,
2020-01-27,,,2,,,,,,,19,,,,,,,
2020-01-28,,,1,1,,,1,,,11,,,,,,,
2020-01-30,,,0,2,,,2,,,27,,,,,,,
2020-01-31,,,0,2,,,2,,,17,,,,,,,
2020-02-03,,,0,3,,,3,,,29,,,,,,,
2020-02-04,90,12,0,3,,,3,139,,34,,,,,,,
2020-02-05,96,8,0,3,,,3,150,,43,,,,,,,
2020-02-06,104,0,0,3,,,3,169,,62,,,,,,,
2020-02-08,130,25,0,3,,,3,197,,39,,,,,,,
2020-02-10,167,81,0,3,,,3,259,,8,,,,,,,
2020-02-11,184,79,0,3,,,3,285,,19,,,,,,,
2020-02-12,257,44,0,2,1,,3,313,,9,,,,,,,
2020-02-13,306,16,0,2,1,,3,340,,15,,,,,,,
```

The multiple commands represent data that is not recorded or assumed to be 0.

Here is what I have so far and it does not work properly. It only stores the dates properly into the structure.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define NUM_OF_VALUES 999
#define DATE_SIZE 10

FILE *inputFile = 0;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // Used to store first 1024 lines
char *token = 0;
char startDate;
char endDate;

typedef struct covid {
    char reportedDate[50];
    char confirmedNegative[50];
    char presumptiveNegative[50];
    char presumptivePostitive[50];
    char confirmedPositive[50];
    char resolved[50];
    char deaths[50];
    char totalCases[50];
    char totalPatientsApprovedForTesting[50];
    char totalTestsCompletedInLastDay[50];
    char underInvestigation[50];
    char numberPatientHospitalizedWithCovid[50];
    char numberofPatientIcuWithCovid[50];
    char numberofPatientIcuVentilatorWithCovid[50];
    char totalPositiveLtcResidentCases[50];
    char totalPositiveLtcHcwCases[50];
    char totalLtcResidentDeaths[50];
    char totalHcwDeaths[50];
}stCovid;

typedef struct extractedCovid {
    char date[50];
    char changeInPatientsInHosptial[50];
    char changeInPatientsInICU[50];
    char changeInPatientsInICUVentilator[50];
}exCovid;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // Force standard output (terminal) to be line-buffered because windows sucks
    
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int c =0;
    int lowerDate = 0;
    int upperDate = 0;
    
    stCovid data[NUM_OF_VALUES];
    exCovid dataExtracted[NUM_OF_VALUES];
    
    inputFile = fopen("covidtesting.csv", "r"); // open file in -> r (read mode)
    if (inputFile == NULL) {
            perror("Error: ");
            return -1;
    }
    
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), inputFile)) { //fgets reads a line from specified stream and stores it into buffer stops when sizeof(buffer) - 1 characters are read or newline character is read.
        col = 0;
        row++;
        if(row == 1) continue; // continue skips an iteration of the while loop so we skip headings
        
        token = strtok(buffer, ","); //split line into strings. every , will be the end of a string.

        while(token) {
            if(col == 0) {
                strcpy(data[i].reportedDate, token);
            }
            if(col == 1) {
                strcpy(data[i].confirmedNegative, token);
                printf("%s\n", data[i].confirmedNegative, token);
            }
            if(col == 2) {
                strcpy(data[i].presumptiveNegative, token);
            }
            if(col == 3) {
                strcpy(data[i].presumptivePostitive, token);
            }
            if(col == 4) {
                strcpy(data[i].confirmedPositive, token);
            }
            if(col == 5) {
                strcpy(data[i].resolved, token);
            }
            if(col == 6) {
                strcpy(data[i].deaths, token);
            }
            if(col == 7) {
                strcpy(data[i].totalCases, token);
            }
            if(col == 8) {
                strcpy(data[i].totalPatientsApprovedForTesting, token);
            }
            if(col == 9) {
                strcpy(data[i].totalTestsCompletedInLastDay, token);
            }
            if(col == 10) {
                strcpy(data[i].underInvestigation, token);
            }
            if(col == 11) {
                strcpy(data[i].numberPatientHospitalizedWithCovid, token);
            }
            if(col == 12) {
                strcpy(data[i].numberofPatientIcuWithCovid, token);
            }
            if(col == 13) {
                strcpy(data[i].numberofPatientIcuVentilatorWithCovid, token);
            }
            if(col == 14) {
                strcpy(data[i].totalPositiveLtcResidentCases, token);
            }
            if(col == 15) {
                strcpy(data[i].totalPositiveLtcHcwCases, token);
            }
            if(col == 16) {
                strcpy(data[i].totalLtcResidentDeaths, token);
            }
            if(col == 17) {
                strcpy(data[i].totalHcwDeaths, token);
            }           
    
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            col++;
        }
        i++;
        
    }
    fclose(inputFile);
    return 0;
```

Comment: I don't think `strtok` would help you here. From the manual "These tokens are separated in the string by at least one of the characters in sep.". So it would only get you so many columns as many values you have, as it treats any number of consecutive occurrences of your separator as one. In other words for `strtok` "," and ",,," is the same.

Comment: I was starting to feel like this was an issue... Any suggestions on a function that would help?

Comment: I would use library, like this one https://github.com/rgamble/libcsv. It's not very user friendly, but it reads your CSV correctly. I've created a gist which reads your file (from stdin) and outputs only existing columns, separated by space, https://gist.github.com/pczajkowski/174c89cb054f1f31fc5e4f0258c27167. Hope it would give you an idea how to use it and that you'll be able to adjust it to your structure. Good luck!

Comment: Alternatively you can read https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 and try to write your own parser. Which could be fun, but I don't know if you're looking for a challenge right now or just want to get your work done.

Comment: I don't think I am allowed to use this library.. I guess I am writing my own parser oh boy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with strsep. since I was on windows I had to implement my own function for strsep but this was easy because it was open source.

```
char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim) {
char *rv = *stringp;
if (rv) {
    *stringp += strcspn(*stringp, delim);
    if (**stringp)
        *(*stringp)++ = '\0';
    else
        *stringp = 0; }
return rv;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeatedly call `strtok()` for every delimited element, with every call after the first having NULL as the first argument. What your code is doing at the moment is only calling it once, so you're only getting the first element from any given line.

Since you have a specific, known number of fields, you could be a bit quick-n-dirty and inside your fgets() loop do something similar to the following:

```
(void) strcpy(reportedDate, strtok(line, ","));
(void) strcpy(confirmedNegative, strtok(NULL, ","));
(void) strcpy(presumptiveNegative, strtok(NULL, ","));
(void) strcpy(presumptivePostitive, strtok(NULL, ","));
```

etc etc.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok is useful.